# Buck-Boost converter without low side switch

Tags: power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, control-system, buck-boost

Please look at the buck -boost converter below. It is 2 outputs, one buck and one boost output.
Would the circuit work as describe in the picture? In what condition the circuit will it work?
If so how would you control those switches?

**EDIT:** I know about conventional buck, boost and buck-boost converter. However, here I am looking for a specific topology as in the figure. I want to know what conditions so that can work like at some load conditions.

[image]

Comment: Your circuit is neither a buck nor a boost nor a buck-boost converter. It is like you draw a resistor and say it's a capacitor and asking if it will work...

Comment: You have a battery connected to an inductor. Then two switches with a capacitor and a current source on the other side? Are I1 and I2 supposed to be self contained buck and boost converters? I don't understand what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Hekete The current sources represent the load. It's common to do so.

Comment: Yeah, the current sources represent the load. 
@Huisman I define buck or boost in relation to their voltage with input voltage. If that voltage is smaller than input voltage then it is buck and vice versa boost converter. 
I do think it will work with some condition but I'm not sure.

Comment: @anhnha but that definition is wrong. A buck converter is using a switched inductor, plus some rectifying element (typically, a diode) that conduct during the *off* time of the switch. Your schematic is missing the diode, so, it's not a buck converter. Same for boost, just that your circuit is even less like a boost converter. So, to answer your question:

Comment: No, your circuit will not work. It's neither buck nor boost, and it doesn't convert a voltage.

Comment: Moreover, you cannot share 1 inductor for 2 outputs (in order to get something useful).

Comment: @Huisman do you know single inductor multiple outputs? that's a common toplology for SIMO.

Comment: I didn't. Interesting technology. It is interleaving between the outputs. I think you drew that using S1 and S2? But there is way more involved than you drew in your schematic.

Comment: @Huisman I know SIMO but they have more switch than just output switches like that. So I am wondering if the one above will work.

Comment: Read more about how Buck-boost works

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 you missed the idea of this. I know the normal buck, boost or a buck-boost converter with four switches. However, I'm looking for something more not just a typical one.
The one above is just a special case.

Comment: @anhnha  I think you missed the fact that both your switches are identical , just alternate cycles and missing the boost config

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 assume that with some kind of controller, there's two outputs. One is lower than input (so let's call it buck even it is not a real buck) and another output larger than input (boost). So the inductor current has two states, S1 ON charging inductor current and S2 ON discharging inductor. If it can be controlled somehow so volt-sec and cap-charge balance principles are met then it can work in some condition.

Comment: No controller will boost your output under any condition

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 that's not right. I simulated with some load conditions and it works.

Comment: Sorry but the fundamentals should tell you to expect   an unstable switched LC oscillation for "boost" possibly,  with high Q and horribly interdependent with shared L

Answer (score 0):

Here is a research paper on a 5 output version: [5 Output SIMO](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2983666_A_Single-Inductor_Switching_DC-DC_Converter_With_Five_Outputs_and_Ordered_Power-Distributive_Control#pf4). As you can see the control system is fairly complex.

I think I understand what you want to do. You want to take this standard single inductor, multiple output design and reduce it to just the switches before each capacitor like so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcYyJE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You want to have M4 buck in discontinuous mode, but then M5 will drain Lind to boost and it will be like M4 is actually in continuous mode?

I think this might be possible if you have very stable loads that would allow you to precisely calibrate your values?

I don't have enough experience to give you a definite answer, we will need someone more knowledgeable on the subject. I'm mostly posting this to give someone else more information to figure this out, since the comments suggested people didn't know what you were asking.

Comment: well, this is a normal topology and easy to do. My idea above is just use two switch and ask in what condition will it work.

Comment: So you want to get rid of all the switches except M4 and M5?

Comment: Yes, I am asking about that special topology. And ask can it work under some conditions.

Comment: Yes, only M4 and M5. M4 charges the inductor and M5 discharges it. I think it can work in some load conditions.

Comment: I think it might be able to work with very stable load conditions, but I will leave it open for someone that has better knowledge on the subject.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are many conditions for failure as shown.. The question and answer circuit lack fundamental diodes and configuration necessary for conversion.

Comment: There are diodes, they are in those MOSFETs? What is missing is how the control system works.